# ValidationError: planModel validation failed: price: Path `price` is required,duration: Path `duration` is required., name: Path `name` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As I am trying to save the data through the Postman into the `Mongodb` with Mongoose (by keeping all data in perfect, Body>raw>JSON). But, I am Still getting the `ValidationError`.

I have tried previous Solution on this platform but got no solution that's why I am posting it, please anyone resolve it. I am trying it by three days to resolve.

This is How I created `UserSchema`.

```js
const Planschema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 20,
  },

  duration: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },

  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },

  ratingAverage: {
    type: Number,
  },

  discount: {
    type: Number,
    validate: function () {
      return this.discount < 100
    },
  },
})
```

This is the way I am trying to Save the data:-

```js
module.exports.createPlan = async function createPlan(req, res) {
  let data = req.body

  // First I have tried this Way

  // let createData = await planModel.create(data);

  // After failing to save that way I used this way too.
  let doc = new planModel(data)
  let userdetails = await doc.save()
  res.json({
    message: 'Data has been Created',
    data: userdetails,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check if your body is defined or not. If not, ensure that the bodyParser at the root of your project is implemented :
Considering the last version of express, you could do :

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Or use the body-parser package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: If you can mark my answer as resolved and upvote my answer :-)